# How to detect in TextInput height has reached 50%

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to detect if your `Textinput` component's height has change and then trigger something. e.g:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  //if the line heigh has reached 50%
  console.log('Input has reach 50%')
}, []);

<TextInput styles={{maxHeight: '50%'}} multiline={true} />
```

I don't know where to begin... please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `useLayout` hook from **@react-native-community/hooks**. This allows you to dynamically keep track of the height,width,etc.. of a component.

1. First install it `npm install @react-native-community/hooks`
2. Then just do something like this below.

```js
import { useLayout } from '@react-native-community/hooks'


export default function App() {
    // Use the hook
    const { onLayout, ...layout } = useLayout()

    
    // Check for when the height changes
    useEffect(()=>{
         console.log(layout.height);
    },[layout.height])


    // Lastly place it in the component you wish to track
    return (
        <> 
          <TextInput 
           onLayout={onLayout} 
           styles={{maxHeight: '50%'}} 
           multiline={true} />
        </>
    )

}
```